# Spring Cloud Contract : not able to resolve latest version of stubs in local repo

Tags: java, aether, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using Spring Cloud Contract 1.0.2.RELEASE and I'm able to publish the stucs in my local Maven repo.

On the consumer side, I then configure my test with :

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = {"com.myGroup:myArtifactt:+:8080"}, workOffline = true)
```

"+" is supposed to mean I'll get the latest version available in my local repo, but it fails to resolve the dependency. However, if I give the precise version instead of "+" , then it works.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go in debug, you will see that at some point you reach org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.SimpleLocalRepositoryManager class (located in aether-impl-1.0.2.v20150114.jar for me), in which there's this method :

```
public LocalMetadataResult find( RepositorySystemSession session, LocalMetadataRequest request )
```

To resolve the version in your local repo, it's going to try to find a **maven-metadata-local.xml** file under the artifact directory in your local Maven repository (the else block below):

```
    RemoteRepository remote = request.getRepository();

    if ( remote != null )
    {
        path = getPathForRemoteMetadata( metadata, remote, context );
    }
    else
    {
        path = getPathForLocalMetadata( metadata );
    }

    File file = new File( getRepository().getBasedir(), path );
```

It doesn't get logged in case *file* doesn't exist, so make sure you have maven-metadata-local.xml where the repository manager expects it to be : it's supposed to be created when you've installed the stubs in your local repo.

It sometimes happen that you have only the remote one, ie maven-metadata.xml - in that case, jar resolution would fail.